# Concentration of weak acid neutralized by strong base

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, titration

I've got a question that should be simple enough but I must be doing something very wrong.

> A $\pu{10mL}$ sample of $\ce{H2SO3}$ is neutralized by $\pu{18.6mL}$ of a $\pu{0.10M}$ strong base. Find the concentration of the acid.

**My solution:**

1. Given the information, I calculate $\pu{1.86E-3 mol}$ of $\ce{OH-}$ used for this reaction, so an equivalent amount of $\ce{H+}$ ions is assumed. Therefore the $\ce{[H+]} = 1.86 \times 10^{-3} / \pu{0.01L}  =  \pu{0.186M}$.
2. $K_\mathrm{a}$ of sulphurous acid is $1.5\times 10^{-2}$. $K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{\ce{[H+][A-]}}{ \ce{[HA]}}$. Assuming that $\ce{[H+]} = \ce{[A-]}$, the $\ce{[H2SO3]}$ at end of reaction is $\pu{2.3064M}$.

However, this is obviously wrong compared to the given answer, $\pu{0.093M}$. Is the "concentration of acid" *not* $\ce{[HA]}$? Am I making any incorrect assumptions?

Comment: Your title is very wrong. Short of that, you have a common misconception that [H+] matters in the neutralization business. It doesn't.
Also, see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60407/why-will-a-strong-acid-neutralize-as-much-base-as-a-weak-acid/60409#60409

Comment: A strong base would be something like sodium hydroxide which which would react to neutralize both hydrogens of the $\ce{H2SO3}$ molecule.

Comment: @MaxW so how should I change my process based on that information? Something like [H+]^2 [A-] / [HA] = Ka?

Comment: Forget Ka. Just divide 0.186 by two.

Comment: Assuming NaOH for the base, the overall chemical reaction would be: $$\ce{H2SO3 + 2NaOH -> Na2SO3 + 2H2O}$$

Answer (score 2):

A one loose fault of the question is not giving the nature of strong acid. Thus, it is safe to assume that $\ce{NaOH}$ is the strong base, and the overall chemical reaction can be written as:

$$\ce{H2SO3 + 2 NaOH -> Na2SO3 + 2 H2O}$$

Thus, each $\pu{mol}$ of $\ce{H2SO3}$ need $\pu{2 mol}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$ to neutralize. You have correctly calculate  $\pu{1.86 \times 10^{−3} mol}$ of $\ce{OH−}$ used for this neutralization reaction. Therefore, amount of $\ce{H2SO3}$ presence in the $\pu{10.0 mL}$ of solution is $\frac12 \times \pu{1.86 \times 10^{−3} mol} = \pu{9.30 \times 10^{−4} mol}$. Thus, molarity of $\ce{H2SO3}$ solution is:

$$\frac{\pu{9.30 \times 10^{−4} mol}}{\pu{10.0 \times 10^{−3} L}} = \pu{9.30 \times 10^{−2} mol L-1} = \pu{0.093 M}$$